# Get calendar events by OutlookServicesClient

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

I have the same issue reported in this thread [Office365 REST v1.0 API calendar does not return recurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610853/office365-rest-v1-0-api-calendar-does-not-return-recurrences)

The answer says to use https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/CalendarView instead of https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/Events to get all events (including ocurrences of series)

My problem is that I'm using the OutlookServicesClient to call de O365 API. This is how I call the ".../events":

```
var eventsResults = await (from i in outlookServicesClient.Me.Events
                           where i.Start >= start && i.Start <= end
                           orderby  i.Start
                           select i).Take(10).ExecuteAsync();
```

I tried to call the ".../calendarview", in this way:

```
var eventsResults = await (from i in outlookServicesClient.Me.CalendarView
                           where i.Start >= start && i.End <= end
                           orderby  i.Start
                           select i).Take(10).ExecuteAsync();
```

I get an exception that says "startdatetime and enddatetime is required". Looks like the library is not sending the parameters, and my where clause is being transformed to $filter OData query

Is there any way to call CalendarView using the OutlookServicesClient library?

Thank you

Comment: Found the answer to this?

Comment: No. I didn't find a solution. I'm using the outlookServicesClient.Me.Calendar.Events. :(

Answer (score 3):

In case you didn't found answer for your question below is a sample code:

```
var eventsResults = await outlookServicesClient.Me.Calendar.GetCalendarView(new DateTimeOffset(startDate).UtcDateTime, new DateTimeOffset(endDate).UtcDateTime).Take(int.MaxValue).ExecuteAsync();
```

Even if Microsoft is saying that this is not supported you can get CalendarView using Client  Libraries.

Comment: Just found out about the same option. This is the correct answer ( wanted to add this myselve :p )