# Office 365 dll querying Calendarview doesn't support StartDateTime or EndDateTime

Tags: outlook, office365

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613782/get-calendar-events-by-outlookservicesclient)

When querying CalendarView, it doesn't seem to support Start and End ( so they don't get translated into the correct values).

My code returns an error because i didn't include the parameters.

Is there any way to add these parameters through the OutlookServicesClient?

My current code looks like this:

```
            Dim calendarView = exClient.Me.CalendarView
           ' For Each Attendee In AttendeesFilter.Split(New Char() {Char.Parse(";")}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            '    calendarView.Where(Function(dl) dl.Attendees.Any(Function(el) el.EmailAddress.Equals(Attendee)))
           ' Next 'Office365 doesnt seem to filter on attendees

            startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
            endDateTime = DateTime.Now

            If startDate.HasValue AndAlso endDateTime.HasValue Then
                calendarView.Where(Function(dl) dl.Start.Value <= startDate.Value AndAlso dl.End.Value <= endDateTime.Value) 'doesnt seem to filter on dates
            End If
```

The exact error i receive is :

```
Type: Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataErrorException

Message: This request requires a time window specified by the query string parameters startDateTime and endDateTime.
```

Although i can't seem to find a proper way on how to add the time window :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function:

```
exClient.Me.Calendar.GetCalendarView(startDateOffset, endDateOffset)
```

This filters between start and endDate instead of adding it to the Query

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `CalendarView` as follows:

```
var eventResults = await exClient.Me.Calendar
                    .GetCalendarView(startDateTime,endDateTime)
                    .Take(10)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```