# What is the maximum number of events per page returned for calendarview endpoint in Office365 Calendar REST Api?

Tags: api, rest, calendar, office365

As suggested in the answer for this question:

[Office365 REST v1.0 API calendar does not return recurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610853/office365-rest-v1-0-api-calendar-does-not-return-recurrences)

I am using the calendarview endpoint.  Here is the documentation for it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#EventoperationsGetevents

In the documentation is the following link to OData query parameters that discuss the paging of the response:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersPageresults

However, it only mentions the maximum number of entries per page returned for Messages or ChildFolders endpoints, but not the number of entries per page returned for the calendarview endpoint.  I doubt it would be 10 or 50, as that is too few events for a typical calendarview call.

Can someone point me to the documentation that outlines this value?

Answer (score 4):

It is now **1000**:
[Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/)

> [As of 14 Feb 2018] **Increasing page size**: Using the **$top** parameter to increase the number of items returned per page when requesting a set of items. The default page size if the $top parameter is omitted is 10, which isn't very efficient if you're requesting a large number of items. You can increase this limit up to **1000**.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:  Sorry, I didn't understand the question right.  The max # of items returned in a page is 10 if $top isn't specified as a query parameter, value of $top if $ top is specified and $top<=50, and 50 if $top is specified as a query parameter but $top>=50 .  For example:

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/CalendarView?startDateTime=2015-03-01T07:00:00Z&endDateTime=2015-04-01T06:59:59Z would return 10 items in a page, assuming there are at least 10 items to return.

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/CalendarView?startDateTime=2015-03-01T07:00:00Z&endDateTime=2015-04-01T06:59:59Z&$top=50 would return 50 items in a page, assuming there are at least 50 items to return.

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/CalendarView?startDateTime=2015-03-01T07:00:00Z&endDateTime=2015-04-01T06:59:59Z&$top=500 would return 50 items in a page, assuming there are at least 50 items to return.

Comment: So, what is the max # of entries for a given page?  As in, can I set the max entries to 1000?

Comment: I don't think the question is about how next links work, but instead what is the maximum # of entries in a page.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.  Have updated my answer.